# How can I make the jssor slider transition into FADE?

Tags: jquery, css, jssor

I am currently using fullwidth jssor slider.

I want to have the following features:

- Bullet Transition
- Fade Transition
- Disable the dragging or if you use dragging it will do fade transition instead of slide left/right or up/down

Comment: Can we see what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Slideshow transition plays only in 'auto play' manner.

All on demand navigation requests (click on bullet/arrow/thumbnail and manual drag on any slide) will lead sliding left<->right effect.

The following code will enable fade slideshow.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        //Fade
        { $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }
        ];

        var options = {
            ...,
            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

    });
</script>
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-jquery.html

Set `$DragOrientation` option value to 0 will disable drag.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var options = {
            ...,
            $DragOrientation: 0
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

    });
</script>
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html